# How can i get the collection name of a query result item?

Tags: solr

I have a multi-collection solrcloud and need to query through all the collections with a same alias, how can i get the collection name of a result item where it come from? Or I have to put it in a field?

It's a asp.net mvc project and I use SolrNet to connect to solrcloud. I initialized SolrNet with CastleContainer. Here is the configuration. Core1, core2 and core3 has a alias as coreAll.

```
<castle><facilities><facility id = 'solr' type = '***'>
  <solrURL> http://***.***.***.***:****/solr/</solrURL>
  <cores>
    <core id = 'coreAll'>
      <documentType> *** </documentType>
      <url> http://***.***.***.***:****/solr/coreAll</url>
    </core>
    <core id = 'core1'>
      <documentType> *** </documentType>
      <url> http://***.***.***.***:****/solr/core1</url>
    </core>
    <core id = 'core2'>
      <documentType> *** </documentType>
      <url> http://***.***.***.***:****/solr/core2</url>
    </core>
    <core id = 'core3'>
      <documentType> *** </documentType>
      <url> http://***.***.***.***:****/solr/core3</url>
    </core>
  </cores>
</facility></facilities></castle>
```

And here is the code. I use the "coreAll" config to construct the ISolrOperation object like this.

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new StaticContentResource(config)));
var operation = container.Resolve<ISolrOperations<Dictionary<string, object>>>("coreAll");
```

Then send query to Solr to query through all the three collections.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSimilarArticles(ISolrOperations<Dictionary<string, object>> operation, string id, string[] keywords, int keywordCount = 2, int rowCount = 10, bool andQueryLogic = false)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) || keywords.All(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace))
            return new List<string>();

        var filtedKeywords = keywords.Where(k => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(k));
        var query = new SolrQuery(String.Join(" ", filtedKeywords.Take(keywordCount).Select(k => "\"" + k + "\"")));
        var option = new QueryOptions
        {
            Rows = rowCount
        };
        if (andQueryLogic)
        {
            option.ExtraParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("q.op", "AND")
                    };
        }
        var rst = operation.Query(query, option);
        var similars = rst == null || rst.Count == 0
                           ? new List<string>()
                           : rst.Where(i => i.ContainsKey("Id"))
                                .Select(i => i["Id"].ToString())
                                .Except(new[] { id });

        return similars;
    }
```

So my problem is I can't get which collection the item in rst come from. Now I can add a field that contains collection name to each collection to resolve this problem, but is there a better way to do this?

In addition, my solr version is 5.5.0 .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the detail.Thanks for help @manetsus.